# Book on the History of Hong Kong

Tags: china, united-kingdom, reference

I am new to this Stack Exchange community, so please let me know if this question is out of scope.

I am looking for a book on the history of Hong Kong, but I am unsure on whether there are any main references out there. I would like a book that is rigorous yet makes for an enjoyable read. I would like the book to cover the return of the city to Chinese sovereignty so it should be a relatively recent book.

Browsing through the internet, I have found a couple of books that seem close to what I am looking for:

- [*A History of Hong Kong*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/History-Hong-Kong-Frank-Welsh/dp/000638871X/ref=pd_bxgy_14_img_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=1V1K3WS6XAJRFVAAZ0QT), by Frank Welsh;
- [*East and West*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0330373080/ref=s9_acsd_simh_hd_bw_b17GB_c_x_2_w?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-4&pf_rd_r=BRWKYQX3H8PHSJ72YTN8&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=fd347e45-37c2-5ef7-938e-e2348b8d0a86&pf_rd_i=266239), by Chris Patten (last British governor of Hong Kong).

I would like to know if these books (or any other for that matter) are considered "canonical" in this subject.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is merely a 
reference request.

Comment: After [much](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2234/1401) [discussion](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2081/1401) (see meta) we've decided that reference requests are out of scope.  With very few exceptions reference requests are opinion related, subjective and generate more discussion than answers.  Chinese oriented sources will be evaluated differently than British sources, and "enjoyable" and "rigorous" are eminently subjective.

Comment: Aside: I recognize that you're asking whether the source is "canonical", but I think that word rarely applies to recent history. "Canon" is (normally) set by decades of scholarship.